# React Native package server not connected to Android simulator

Tags: android, react-native

I'm running my react native app on an android simulator. My app works fine and is connected with my react-native package server (npm start command I used to start my server) with the android simulator Galaxy J3 series and Galaxy pixel C series. But the same app won't work (packages not loading through server) with the latest Android simulator Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra API 28. It throws an error, **Could not connect to the development server**
Note: I set the dev setting the same to all simulators is same.
Android studio version: 3.6.1
[image]

Build.grdle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching and a lot of trials I end up with the solution. I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` line in `<application` tag in `androidmanifest.xml` file. Then I rerun the app.